# Setting pictures of cards to their name with a PickerView

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a pickerView that I have coded to display the Rank and Suit of all 52 cards in a deck. Under this pickerView I have UIImage that I was to display the image of the card as the card is selected in the PickerView.

This is a very new subject for me and I am not too sure how to approach it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedCard: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardPicker: UIPickerView!

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    var test: String = "(generateDeckOfCards())"

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return theDeck.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {  
        return "\(theDeck[row].rank) of \(theDeck[row].suit)"
    }

    var cardPicked: String = "" //used for saving

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cardPicker.dataSource = self
        cardPicker.delegate = self
        selectedCard.image = UIImage(named: "spade1")
    }
}

struct Card {
 let rank: Rank
 let suit: Suit

enum Rank: Int{
    case two = 2
    case three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
    case Jack, Queen, King, Ace

    func rankDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Jack: return "Jack"
        case .Queen: return "Queen"
        case .King: return "King"
        case .Ace: return "Ace"
        default: return String(self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
enum Suit: String {
    case Diamond = "♦️"
    case Heart = "♥️"
    case Spade = "♠️"
    case Club = "♣️"
}
}
func generateDeckOfCards() -> [Card] {
 var myDeckOfCards: Array = [Card]()
 let maxRank = Card.Rank.Ace.rawValue
 let aSuit: Array = [Card.Suit.Club.rawValue, 
 Card.Suit.Diamond.rawValue, Card.Suit.Heart.rawValue, Card.Suit.Spade.rawValue]

for count in 2...maxRank {
    for suit in aSuit{
        let aRank = Card.Rank.init(rawValue: count)
        let aSuit = Card.Suit.init(rawValue: suit)
        let myCard = Card(rank: aRank!,suit: aSuit!)
        myDeckOfCards.append(myCard)
    }
}
return myDeckOfCards
}
 var theDeck = generateDeckOfCards()
```

My expected results are to set the selectedCard.image to equal whatever is currently selected in the pickerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `Card` struct to this (now you can get the image name):

```
struct Card {

    let rank: Rank
    let suit: Suit

    enum Rank: Int {
        case ace = 1, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
        case jack, queen, king
    }

    enum Suit: String {
        case diamond, heart, spade, club
    }

    var rankDescription: String {
        switch rank {
        case .ace:
            return "Ace"
        case .jack:
            return "Jack"
        case .queen:
            return "Queen"
        case .king:
            return "King"
        default:
            return String(rank.rawValue)
        }
    }

    var suitDescription: String {
        switch suit {
        case .diamond:
            return "♦️"
        case .heart:
            return "♥️"
        case .spade:
            return "♠️"
        case .club:
            return "♣️"
        }
    }


    // Image Name
    var imageName: String {
        return suit.rawValue + String(rank.rawValue)
    }


}

let card = Card(rank: .ace, suit: .diamond)
print(card.imageName) // prints "diamond1"
```

Then inside the picker view's delegate `didSelectRow` method, you can set the selectedCard.image to whatever is currently selected in the UIPickerView:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

     // Get card image
     let image = UIImage(named: "\(theDeck[row].imageName)")

     // Update image
     selectedCard.image = image

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but this will set the image to the pickerView. I have 52 pictures they are for the 52 cards in a deck labeled like this (2 of diamonds = diamond2, ace of hearts = hearts1, King of Spades = Spade13) how would I set each of these images to each row?

Comment: @KinneyKare did you want the images to show up in the `UIPickerView` or in an outside `UIImageView`? I just update my answer for updating a `UIImageView` outside of the `UIPickerView` depending on what is currently selected.

Comment: I have the uipickerview already showing the name of the card. I want the UIImage view (which is positioned below the pickerView in the app) to display the picture of the card the pickerView is displaying.   Ex: pickerView shows Ace of Hearts; I want the UIImage to display the ace of hearts picture.

Comment: @KinneyKare did you try my answer already? I don't know how you are storing the image names so I just added the `.imageName` because it seemed like `theDeck[row]` was returning a Card object or something.

Comment: Your way will not work until you set the image to each card title. That’s where I am getting stuck. If I say 3 of hearts = heart3 then I could set it the the Didselectrow but doing all 52 cards like that seems long and tedious...

Comment: @KinneyKare can you add the card object code. You need to add a function in that will return each cards image name. I will try and help once I know what everything is returning

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. I added the card object to the code above.

Comment: @KinneyKare What are your image names with Jack, Queen, King? Ex: Jack of Spades = "spade11" or "spadeJack"; King of Hearts = "heart13" or "heartKing"?

Comment: Spade11, spade12, spade13  ace of spades = spade1

Comment: @KinneyKare I rewrote your Card struct to make it a little more organized and added some other variables for you. The `imageName` should return the desired name for your selected card.

Comment: are you saying to remove the generateDeckOfCards() ?

Comment: @KinneyKare you should put that function outside of the `Card` struct and into the view controller because it is generating `Card`s and doesn’t have to do with the `Card` object itself.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to help me get this solved. It it working perfectly. If you have twitter I would love to follow you!!

Comment: @KinneyKare no problem glad it worked! I don't have a twitter right now but maybe I'll make one soon..!